# karate - how to validate that param is string and having max length

Tags: karate

In karate, how to check if in the response, name field is string type and having max length upto 35. I know how to validate, string, but don't know how to check the length at same time.

name: '#string',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are pretty close,

```
"#string? _.length <= 35"
```

`_` means `self` in expressions

refer ['self' validation expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions)